# HighCharts : Remove auto margin for errorBar

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with the errorBar of HighCharts. The errorBar adds a margin in the chart, but i don't want this margin.

So i deleted it with this code :

```
xAxis: [{
    [...]
    /* Remove padding */
    min: pointStart,
    max: pointEnd,
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
    /* End remove padding */
}]
```

`pointStart` and `pointEnd` are calculated for remove a static margin. It's working for column type but with errorBar type the margin is not constant and it's impossible to removed them because i think it's a random margin.

There is another solution to remove the auto margin of errorBar ?

### Edit

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/cPq7Y/2/) *// edited link*

In this demo you see 3 graphics. The problem is that the graphics needs exactly the  same xAxis. The errorBar adds margins, but in my production code I have dynamic data and the margin is random for me.

Comment: Well, could you recreate this on jsFiddle? I'm not sure what kind of margin you are talking about. Maybe it's caused by `pointPadding` or `groupPadding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by setting `pointPlacement: 'between'`. Remove that line and will be working fine, see third chart: http://jsfiddle.net/cPq7Y/1/

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/cPq7Y/2/) Thx, but there has not exactly the same xAxis between graph line and graph errorBar :s

Comment: Do you mean first two separate charts? In that case how about adding some 'shadow' error bar series to have the same series types on both charts? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cPq7Y/3/

Comment: It's a solution but it's not possible to catch the start time of the graphic because i don't know the margin added by Highcharts

Comment: What do you mean by start time? I'm a bit lost :)

Comment: Sorry... In my graphic i have a starting point and a ending point on the xAxis. I need to know **exactly** value (in UTC date) of these points. I need to get or set these points.

Comment: Ah, right, I forget about initial question. Sorry, but there's not such option like margin for error bars.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51283/discussion-between-r3tep-and-pawel-fus)

Comment: I updated the library to remove the margin. HighCharts V3.0.9 line 7092 I replaced : `if (axis.isXAxis || hasCategories) {` by `if (false) {`